# Variable name from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this possible?

```
i = 1
for var in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']:
    eval(var) = i
    i + 1
```

Somehow I want to create a new variable (with new name) with each loop.

**[EDIT:]**
A lot of people said, it's not useful so below is my actual code I wanted to use it for:

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert categorical variables to dummies
PPE_WAW_DISTRICT = pd.get_dummies(X['PPE_WAW_DISTRICT'], prefix='PPE_WAW_DISTRICT')
PPE_TARIFF_TYPE = pd.get_dummies(X['PPE_TARIFF_TYPE'], prefix='PPE_TARIFF_TYPE')
PPE_OSD = pd.get_dummies(X['PPE_OSD'], prefix='PPE_OSD')
VariantProdEE = pd.get_dummies(X['VariantProdEE'], prefix='VariantProdEE')
CUS_OWNER = pd.get_dummies(X['CUS_OWNER'], prefix='CUS_OWNER')
CUS_LEGAL_FORM = pd.get_dummies(X['CUS_LEGAL_FORM'], prefix='CUS_LEGAL_FORM')
CUS_CITY = pd.get_dummies(X['CUS_CITY'], prefix='CUS_CITY')
CUS_DISTRICT = pd.get_dummies(X['CUS_DISTRICT'], prefix='CUS_DISTRICT')

X.drop(['PPE_WAW_DISTRICT', 'PPE_TARIFF_TYPE', 'PPE_OSD', 'CUS_OWNER', 
               'CUS_LEGAL_FORM', 'CUS_CITY', 'CUS_DISTRICT'], axis=1, inplace=True)

X = pd.concat([PPE_WAW_DISTRICT, PPE_TARIFF_TYPE, PPE_OSD, VariantProdEE,
              CUS_OWNER, CUS_LEGAL_FORM, CUS_CITY, CUS_DISTRICT], axis=1)
```

Basically I want to create dummy columns from each of the selected oclumns and then with prefix add it to main dataframe (X)

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: It is possible, but why would it be desirable? `exec('{} = {}'.format(var, i))`

Comment: Possible but not useful. Whatever you need to do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @khelwood please look at my edit. I want basically change above code into loop

Comment: How would you then use the variables?

Comment: @MateuszKonopelski You do not need different variable names for every loop iteration.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ah your are right! I over-complicated it. I could do one column at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly do not want to do this, but if for some reason you still really want to you can do

```
i = 1
for var in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']:
    exec(var + "=" + str(i))
    i += 1
```

or for compactness,

```
for i, var in enumerate(['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'], 1):
    exec(var + "=" + str(i))
```

but as everyone else is saying, use a dictionary!